# can someone please help me solve this class problem

Tags: python

So the problem is that the class enemy is being called a local variable in the loop and thus will not create the enemy entities the syntax is this

```
line 98, in <module>
     loop()
File "/home/trystanwipf/tower defencec game/the main game.py", line 92, in loop
     wt.append(Enemys('n',1,'white')) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'Enemys' referenced before assignment
```

```
        #enemys
        class Enemys(turtle.Turtle):
            def __init__(self,ability,healthp,color):
                turtle.Turtle.__init__(self)
                self.penup()
                self.speed(0)
                self.color(color)
                self.hp=healthp
                self.power=ability
                self.goto(-370,250)
                self.setheading(0)
            def run_path(self,sp):
                global player_lives
                self.forward(sp)
                if self.xcor()==-170:
                    self.setheading(-90)
                if self.ycor()==-110:
                    self.setheading(0)
                if self.xcor()==220:
                    self.setheading(90)
                if self.xcor()==220 and self.ycor()==250:
                    self.setheading(0)
                if self.xcor()==370:
                    self.setheading(0)
                    self.hideturtle()
                    self.goto(-370,250)
                    player_lives-=1
                    self.showturtle()


        def lives():
            pen.clear()
            pen.goto(250,270)
            pen.write('lives:{}'.format(player_lives),font=('times new roman',14,'normal'))
        
        
        wt=[]
        def loop():
            w.tracer(0)
            global run
            run=True
            while run==True:
                w.update()
                #if len(wt)<=7:
                    #wt.append(Enemys('n',1,'white'))
                for Enemys in wt:
                    Enemys.run_path(10)
                lives()
                if player_lives<=0:
                    run=False
        loop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The line which the error occurs is commented out, so this isn't the error that the code you pasted is represented with.  Also note that you are overwriting the definition of ```Enemys``` in the ```for Enemys in wt:``` loop.  Use a different variable. Also, what is ```w```?

Comment: Is there a way to not overwrite the definition but still being able to move the pepole